# Have custom Nginx error page when All backend servers unhealty

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, production-environment

I am using Nginx Plus AWS EC2 image for my production environment. 
I use the health checks module to see the availability of backend servers. When all the servers are unhealthy. Then nginx returns a 404 error screen.

I am unable to find the HTML for that. I need to configure that.

Any ideas how can I find that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `proxy_next_upstream` [1] to specify case when the request be passed to the next backend, e.g. 502 error, etc. When the backend is unavailable, or all of them are unvailable when using proxy_next_upstream, a 502 error will be returned. You can specify which file is served in this situation.

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        error_page 502 /50x.html;
    }
```

Define location for 50x.html, otherwise it will go back to the "/" location.

```
location /50x.html {
    }
```

[1] http://nginx.org/r/proxy_next_upstream

Note: NGINX Plus comes with commercial support. To access support visit http://nginx.com/ami-support-activation and enter your AWS Account Number.